# Coveo error when accessing index manager: No SecurityProviderConversionHelper found for index: Coveo_master_index

Tags: coveo

I've installed Coveo (pro cloud edition with the October 2016 package), and after installation I went and changed the farm name and Sitecore account it was using (the account I switched to is still an administrator account). When I tried to access the diagnostic page, I got a YSOD message with "No SecurityProviderConversionHelper found for index: Coveo_master_index." Looking around, I thought it could be because I hadn't kicked off an initial index yet, but when I go to the indexing manager, I get the same error. I don't see this message around the developer or answers sites on Coveo, so assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug introduced with the October package (4.0.450) happening when upgrading and changing the Sitecore account. We are looking for solutions on our side.

Comment: Thanks - I submitted a ticket like we discussed on Slack, so I should be in the system now.

Comment: Hotfix confirmed to be coming soon, will post the link when it's done for folks to know about.

Comment: Should note, Coveo sent me a hot fix for the issue, but has also updated the October release to version 704, which should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you synchronize after you changed the farm name? You could also do a reindex or a publish.

But I recommend you making sure the configs look good, followed by doing a security cache flush and synchronize.